# Spring boot cannot create session

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I am getting the following exception when creating the session.

```
    INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION
(
    SESSION_ID, 
    CREATION_TIME, 
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME, 
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL, 
    PRINCIPAL_NAME
) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];
```

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PRIMARY_ID'

Following are my schema details :

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES IMAGE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY 
(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY 
(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_IX1 
ON SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is simple , Inside of spring-session jar file , there is org/springframework/session/jdbc folder , you can view this in eclipse.

Under this folder you can get schema-sqlserver.sql file , you need to execute this file only for proper schema of spring session.

Comment: Yah, the schema changed in different versions of spring session.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the Column `PRIMARY_ID` as Primary key

```
CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
```

and since it is not a computed column or Auto Incremented one, you must specify a value for this column on each insert.

But wish not to populate the column for all Rows, then Change the design and Remove the PRIMARY KEY from that Column.

Then Probably you may add a New Column with IDENTITY so that it will be automatically assigned.

You can drop the Constraint Using this

```
ALTER TABLE SPRING_SESSION 
DROP CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK
```

Then add New Primary Key

```
ALTER TABLE SPRING_SESSION 
ADD SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: There are so many dependencies on them The constraint 'SPRING_SESSION_PK' is being referenced by table 'SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES', foreign key constraint 'SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK'.

Comment: In that case you will have to re-create them all based on the new design

Comment: Could you please suggest or is there any example that can be used

Comment: Please check my answer . Appreciating you for your help :)